# Local Branch Recovery

Tags: xcode, git

I had a branch with changes (not stashed or committed) and from that I have created a new sub-branch. It was said 'All uncommited changes will be preserved on the new branch.'. I thought they are also preserve in the initial branch, so I have done some tests in the sub-branch and deleted it (again without stash or commit). I checked out to the initial branch and my changes are gone.

Is there any possibility to recover my changes that have been transferred to the now deleted sub-branch?

Comment: Had you _added_ the files to the staging area (a.k.a. index)?

Comment: Please be aware that there are no such things as sub-branches. Always commit changes or stash them before switching branches. The commit is the history and with it the data can be recovered.

Comment: Uncommitted work (not so much "uncommitted changes" as Git deals with entire snapshots, rather than changesets) is not on *any branch at all*. Switching branches, if it's allowed without `--force`, keeps the uncommitted work as uncommitted work by not touching it at all: it was on *no branch at all* and it still is on *no branch at all*.

Answer (score 2):

As far as git goes : the only files that are stored in git are commits (and the stash, and to some extent the files that are `git add`ed and not committed yet)

The sentence "All uncommited changes will be preserved on the new branch" indicates that git *doesn't delete the files from your disk* when you switch branches, but it doesn't keep them in its internal storage either.

---

If you have deleted untracked files from your disk, check if your IDE has its own "file history" mechanism to restore past files, or turn to a file recovery utility for your system.